# How to calculate average TPR, TNR, FPR, FNR - Multiclass Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

[image]how to calculate Average TPR, TNR, FPR, FNR in case of imbalanced dataset?

example FPR: [3.54224720e-04 0.00000000e+00 1.59383505e-05 0.00000000e+00]
So, can I calculate to sum of 4 class and divided by 4?

TPR :[3.54224720e-04 + 0.00000000e+00 + 1.59383505e-05 + 0.00000000e+00]/4 = 0.99966 ?

And how to calculate 3.54224720e-04 it is equal .000354224720 ?

Thank you

```
FP = np.sum(matrix, axis=0) - np.diag(matrix)
FN = np.sum(matrix, axis=1) - np.diag(matrix)
TP = np.diag(matrix)
TN = np.sum(matrix) - (FP + FN + TP)

# True Positive rate
TPR = TP/(TP+FN)
print("TPR:", TPR)
# True Negative Rate
TNR = TN/(TN+FP)
print("TNR:", TNR)
# False Positive Rate
FPR = FP/(FP+TN)
print("FPR:", FPR)
# False Negative Rate
FNR = FN/(TP+FN)
print("FNR:", FNR)

# Overall accuracy
ACC = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)
print("ACC :", ACC)
```

Comment: R in TPR stands for recall ??

Comment: R for Rate - True Positive Rate

Comment: 1.do you have multiple TPRs from different runs and you want to end up with one? 
2. what do you mean by imbalanced dataset and why should it matter for the calculation ?

Comment: In my dataste there is 4 class instances. If you see the scree shot, TPR is coming separately for each class. I am little bit confuse regarding there is any difference between balance and imbalanced calculation. I didnot consider the Accuracy from here, regarding accuracy i did separate calculation correctly classified instances against incorrectly instances because of Imbalanced dataset print("Accuracy Score:" + str(accuracy_score(yTest.argmax(axis=1), yPred.argmax(axis=1)))). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of measuring the average of the metrics. if you check the packages e.g. [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html), you see there are multiple parameters that you can give. either micro, macro, weighted, and etc.

if you want to calculate them manually, one way(micro) is to get different TP, FN, FP, and TN values from your four different outputs and sum them up together, and then calculate your metrics.

So, you should really understand your problem and to see which one makes sense. Mostly, in the case of imbalanced data, it is better to use the weighted average. Keep in mind that if you have any baseline calculation, you have to use the exact same method for calculating these values to give a fair comparison since there can be huge differences between different ways of averaging.

and yes, those two numbers are equal.

## Update:

As the documentation shows:

> Weighted average: Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.

[this question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compute-for-the-overall-Precision-and-Recall-Do-I-get-the-Precision-and-Recall-for-each-class-and-get-the-average) is also related.

In your case for weighted metrics, you calculate each metric for each of your 4 classes separately. having the number of instances in each of the classes, you calculate the weighted average metric. This pictures shows the equaation for the weighted precision:

[image]

Comment: if you needed an example, let me know to edit my answer.

Comment: I would like to provide weighted avg TP, FP, TN, FN pls. can you pls help me how to calculate from my existing method and codes. and pls how to calculate 3.54224720e-04 it is equal .000354224720 ?

Comment: yes, those two numbers are equal. 
I update the answer with the example.